# Out of memory error for more than a day. Code does not run

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, out-of-memory

I made a Slackbot with Google Apps Script and everything was fine until yesterday I started getting `Out of memory error` out of nowhere. Now I can't even run any of my working code. Has anyone encountered something similar? Not even `console.log()` will print, it just gives the same error. I tried running a simple function with `console.log()` in it and that didn't work either.

This is the code in my project. I wrote an infinite loop before to do spreadsheet actions but now it is removed.

```
function test() {
  console.log("1");
}
```

Comment: Screenshot?  Have you tried creating a new script project? Consider creating a issue in the issue tracker, if issue prevails. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: A new script project works. My current one doesn't tho.

Comment: You're welcome @DarkWheel! If creating a new project and using the code there works, there you have a solution! If you have some free time, you can check the current executions on the Apps Script dashboard. There is a possibility that the loop still running in a past execution, and that may cause this error. You can have more information about managing executions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard#manage_executions).

Comment: Yeb I guess that is my solution. Where can I check if the loop is sitll running from dashboard? I wana see if I can terminate it there.

Answer (score 1):

The `Out of memory error` alert occurs because a variable grew too much on size. Without looking at your code I can't point which variable caused this behaviour, but I can help you in the right direction: first of all make sure that you are not saving all the data in a single variable. After that, check that there is no infinite loop in the code.

I hope to have helped you, but if you keep facing the problem don't hesitate to share the code so I can help you better.

Comment: Hi, how do I share the code with you? Do I share it over google? If so please let me know your email. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So I tried commenting out all the code and leave this instead, still throws out of memory error. I am starting to think that the problem is on google side....note that I did have an infinite loop before the problem occurs and I deleted it, so maybe it caused something on the google's end.

function test() {
  console.log("1");
}

Comment: Hi @DarkWheel! I tested the piece of code that you wrote on the comment, but I don't find any errors with it. If the code is not very large, you can copy it in your original question. Otherwise you can share a copy of the project to anyone with the link; you can have more information about sharing files [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating#collaborating_with_project_sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There are no other code in my project, everything else is commented out. And I cannot share the project since it is within company domain. I did write an infinite loop before the error occurs and even tho it is now removed the problem persists. I'll add the code to my original post.